# how do you split a string of numbers into separate integers and use those in a loop? (java)

Tags: java, loops, relationships

i have a project wherein i have to create multiple classes that form the image of each (ex: Digit0, Digit1,...,Digit9) with a small and a large size. there are 10 different classes so i'll just simplify to what's important. (for example class Digit1 contains a print function that outputs a small number 1 or a big number 1). i have no problem creating the classes for these digits, where i'm stuck is in figuring out the tester program.

the tester program should allow the user to input a number (ex: 1, 25, 4354435454 etc.) and input a size (1 for small, and 2 for large) and print out the desired images. so far i have this code and it works but it only allows single digit numbers

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DigitDisplay
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int digits = scan.nextInt();
        int segmentSize = scan.nextInt();
        while ((digits!=0)&&(segmentSize!=0)) //terminates when 0 0 is input
        {
            if (digits==0)
            {
                if (segmentSize==1) //this is the small size
                {
                    Digit0 small = new Digit0(1); 
                         //this references the small sized 0 created as a method in class Digit0
                    System.out.println(small.toString());                
                         //this prints the small digit 0
                }
                else //this is the large size
                {
                    Digit0 big = new Digit0(2);
                    System.out.println(big.toString()); 
                }
            } 
            //...the other digits are placed as else ifs
        }
    }
}
```

i tried altering the scanner objects so that it takes in String digits instead of int digits. so that i could simply split it and use a for loop to go through each character of the string, but i can't seem to get it to work. i really hope i made sense here. i'm a beginner and would really appreciate the help

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DigitDisplay
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 
        String digits = scan.next(); //takes in a string of numbers
        digits.split(" "); //splits the string into its digits
        //int segmentSize = scan.nextInt();  commenting this out because it works. just need to focus on the 
                                             digits themselves
        while ((!digits.equals("0")) && (segmentSize!=0)) //terminates when input is 0 0 
        {
            for (int i=0; i<digits.length(); i++) //goes through all digits of string
            {
                int num = digits.charAt(i);
                switch (num)
                {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("zero");  //there is a longer code referencing the two sizes but the sizes work but i simplified it again. this is just for me to know whether it is printing the right thing
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("other"); //these are the other digits, but i just condensed them together just to see if its printing right
                    break;
                }
             }
             digits = scan.next();
             digits.split(" ");
             //segmentSize = scan.nextInt();
       }
    }
}
```

when i input 002, i want to ouput:

```
zero
zero
other
```

but instead, it just outputs "other" for all three.

Comment: try using nextLine() instead of next(). nextLine() grabs the entire line and once you have that you should have no problem splitting and parsing. You are also not creating a String[] and setting it the split() call

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the question, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 
String digits = scan.nextLine(); //takes in a string of numbers.

int[] digits_split = new int[0];  //creates an int array to store split digits.
digits_split = digits.split(" "); //splits the string into the digits_split array.
```

By creating an int array it's now easier to validate the digits.

now you can use this loop to check your split digits:

note below is Pseudo Code and has not been tested...

```
      for(int i = 1; i <= digits.length; i++)
     {
         if(digits_split[i]=0)
             {
               System.out.println("zero");
             } 
          else 
            {
                System.out.println("other");
            }
     }
```

Also ensure that when entering your digits you put a space in between each one so when the program requests for digits you type: 0 0 2

EDIT:

If your digits contain commas use:

```
   digits = digits.replace(",","");
```

Also once you've split the string use trim:

```
   digits = digits.trim();
```

It tidy's things up a little.

ALSO:

> when i input 002, i want to ouput:

You need to input: (0[space]0[space]2) to get the output you want. As you're splitting on a " ". Otherwise use a symbol.

Hope this helps,

Rob.

Comment: you can't set an integer array equal to the return of the split method because the split method returns an array of strings, not an array of integers

Comment: Thank you for the feedback solution: split the string into a string array then convert to a int array. Helps with validation.